# PHP create json file tree structure from flat array

Tags: php

I have a method which looks through a directory and returns an array of the file structure, an example of this is as follows;

```
Array
(
    [0] => filename.png
    [directory] => Array
        (
            [subdirectory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => filename.jpg
                )

        )

    [directory] => Array
        (
            [0] => filename.png
        )

    [directory] => Array
        (
        )

    [directory] => Array
        (
            [0] => filename.png
        )

    [directory] => Array
        (
            [0] => filename.png
        )

)
```

The code that I used to build that up is as follows;

```
function dirToArray($dir) {
    $contents = array();

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $node) {
        if ($node == '.' || $node == '..') continue;

        if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $node)) {
            $contents[$node] = dirToArray($dir . '/' . $node);
        } else {
            $contents[] = $node;
        }
    }

    return $contents;
}
```

I need flatten this down so i can display it, exactly like what you see here;

```
filename.png
directory
.. subdirectory
.. .. filename.png
directory
.. filename.png
directory
.. filename.png
directory
.. filename.png
```

The problem is, i need to input the data in a json structure that doesnt change.
The description of the structure is as follows: Full path to the file then text to display and lastly 'leaf' ( file = true, directory = false )

This is how it should look;

```
[ ['fullpath', 'displaytext', 'true'],['fullpath', 'displaytext', 'false'] ]
```

I'm really confused on how to go about this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post us the code on how you've work on that so far?

Comment: @eeya .. Sorry about that .. I've just edited my question

Comment: Did you solve your problem now?

Comment: @eeya no, im not sure where to start turning it into the required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be:

```
 $res=[]; 
 function flatten ($in, $dir, $dots, &$result) { 
   $tmp = [];
   if (is_array($in)) { 
     $tmp[0] = $dir;
     $tmp[1] = $dots.'Directory'; //displaytext
     $tmp[2] = false;
     $result[] = $tmp;
     $dots = $dots.'.. ';
     foreach($in as $k => $v) flatten($v, $dir.'/'.$k, $dots, $result); 
   } else {
     $tmp[0] = $dir.'/'.$in;
     $tmp[1] = $dots.$in; //displaytext
     $tmp[2] = true;
     $result[] = $tmp;
   }
 }
 flatten($array, '','', $res); //$array is the array you created
 echo json_encode($res);
```

But the code is not tested. The idea is to concationate the keys (directories) recursively, until you reach the leafs (files), and store everything in an array that gets passed by reference.

The last edit should finally fix it.

Comment: This is looking good ... But how would i add the .. before directories and .. .. before subdirectories ... Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks @ManuelOtto. Too easy to forget :)

Comment: @BigJobbies, I'm not sure where you want the dots could you elaborate.

Comment: @jh1711 if you scroll up to the question, the text needs to output the same as that ... i.e filename.png
directory
.. subdirectory
.. .. filename.png
directory
.. filename.png
directory
.. filename.png
directory
.. filename.png

Comment: @jh1711 actually, i'll show you exactly what i mean with the output generated by your answer :) ... I'll just hack up a pastebin and be right back

Comment: @jh1711 https://pastebin.com/cgKve3ss sorry about the mess, im really finding it difficult getting my head around it as well

Comment: Ok that looks like we need to count the levels for the displaytext, and maybe change the order. Edit incoming. Is the order important?

Comment: @jh1711 thank you so much ... Yes the order needs to be the same as whats spit out by the array, like traversing a directory tree

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157957/discussion-between-jh1711-and-bigjobbies).